# Multiple Django sites on a single SSL certificate using a single IP with Apache

Tags: apache-2.2, virtualhost, django, mod-ssl, ssl-certificate

Is it technically possible to setup multiple Django sites using a single SSL certificate on a single IP address with Apache?

Below is an excerpt from my SSL config:

```
Alias /media/ x:/home/djang-apps/myapp
WSGIScriptAlias / x:/home/djang-apps/myapp/apache/django.wsgi

<Directory x:/home/djang-apps/>
   Order allow,deny
   Allow from all
</Directory>
```

One of the issues I've come up against is since I only have a single IP address I have only 1 virtual host therefore how can I reference the varius media folders that contain the css/images/js etc for each Django website as well as the WSGIScriptAlias for each site?

I currently have a wild card certificate for *.foo.com

So I would like to be able to add several sites in this fashion:

website1.foo.com
website2.foo.com
website3.foo.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to configure a `NameVirtualHost` directive, and configure a `VirtualHost` for each different domain.

For example:

```
NameVirtualHost *:443

<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName app1.foo.com
    ServerAlias www.app1.foo.com
    SSLEngine On
    SSLCertificateFile x:/path/to/cert.pem
    SSLCertificateKeyFile x:/path/to/cert.key
    # Any other basic config, logging, etc..
    DocumentRoot x:/home/djang-apps/app1
    # Any other document mapping; that Alias directive, WSGIScriptAlias, etc
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName app2.foo.com
    ServerAlias www.app2.foo.com
    SSLEngine On
    SSLCertificateFile x:/path/to/cert.pem
    SSLCertificateKeyFile x:/path/to/cert.key
    # Any other basic config, logging, etc..
    DocumentRoot x:/home/djang-apps/app2
    # Any other document mapping; that Alias directive, WSGIScriptAlias, etc
</VirtualHost>
```

Apache may do some whining during startup about Server Name Indication, which you can safely ignore since you're using a wildcard certificate (just make sure that the SSL directives in each vhost all point to the wildcard cert).

Comment: many thanks, I had managed to get it to work before you answered my question, however Apache was complaining so I thought I was doing something wrong, but now I know why and I can ignore it thanks to you!